# Some code works fine and sometime get Fatal error in mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

Its a pagination code on php and mysql. I have include the same code in two pages (news and user) The code works fine in news where as in user page the code does works sometime but most of the time i get the wired error saying   `"Fatal error: SQL in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/NDFUND/admin/include/page.php on line 6".`

Any help would be appreciated . The code is following which file name is page.php This page include 2 global variable which is define on news.php and user.php. one is $tbl_name and other is $rowsperpage

```
<?php
require_once('../Connections/ndConn.php'); 


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $ndConn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$numrows = $r[0];




$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);


if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
// cast var as int
$currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {

$currentpage = 1;
} // end if
if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
$currentpage = $totalpages;
} 
if ($currentpage < 1) {

$currentpage = 1;
} // end if
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $ndConn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$range = 2;
if ($currentpage > 1) {

$pagination =  " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=1'>[ First ]</a> ";

$prevpage = $currentpage - 1;

$pagination .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage'>[ < ]</a> ";
} 

 for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {

if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {

  if ($x == $currentpage) {

     $pagination .= " <span class=\"selected\">[ $x ]</span> ";

  } else {

     $pagination .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x'>[ $x ]</a> ";
   } 
   } 
 } 


if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {

$nextpage = $currentpage + 1;

$pagination .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$nextpage'>[ > ]</a> ";

$pagination .= " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$totalpages'>[ Last ]</a>   ";
} 

?>
```

Comment: can you publish the code

Comment: What we can do? We know exactly nothing about your code...

Comment: there you go guys i've pulished the code as well

Comment: print the value of `$sql` before line 6. What does it say? Ensure that `$ndConn` is a valid mysql resource. Try changing `"SQL"` to `mysql_error()` in line 6. What happens?

Comment: When i print the value of sql it say "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user" which is right.

Answer (score 0):

This is where your error comes from:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $ndConn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```

So that's wired nor weird, since you put it there yourself. There has to be an error in the SQL statement you're trying to execute.

Simply removing the `or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR)` will show the underlying error, which you can then solve.

My guess is that `$tbl_name` is not set.

Comment: yes @CodeCaster but the problem is it works fine on one page but not the other and by the way i tried removing that i still am getting same problem

Comment: No, if you remove the "or trigger_error" part, you will get an error from MySQL explaining what went wrong. And if you print the query, you can execute it yourself in for example phpMyAdmin, to see if the query is OK.

Comment: the query is fine and just let u know i am still getting the results just sometime it doesn't work on user.php page where as it works fine on news.php.

Comment: Code doesn't just "work sometimes". Let the error show and print the query and when you get an error, look at what's wrong with the query.